# StoreKit problem while restoring In-App Purchase

Tags: swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

I tried to find a tutorial about IAP, and I found : [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_oVUIN7ZJQ)

But when I call function to restore, nothing happens. OnTap button I call : store.restorePurchase()

```
extension Store {
    func product(for identifier: String) -> SKProduct? { ...}
    func purchaseProduct (_ product: SKProduct){ ...}
    func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        print("restore")
    }
}
```

restore is print in my console. It is the only thing that is printed in console. But in the code above, you can see .restored:that should print "UserIsPremium"

```
extension Store : SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions : [SKPaymentTransaction]){
        for transaction in transactions {
            var shouldFinishTransaction = false
            switch transaction.transactionState{
            case .purchased, .restored:
                completedPurchases.append(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                print("UserIsPremium")
                shouldFinishTransaction = true
            case .failed:
                print("NotPremium")
                shouldFinishTransaction = true
            case .deferred, .purchasing:
                print("...")
                break
            @unknown default:
                print("unknown")
                break
            }
            if shouldFinishTransaction {
                print("shouldfinish")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.purchaseCompletionHandler?(transaction)
                    self.purchaseCompletionHandler = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My class Store :

```
import StoreKit

typealias FetchCompletionHandler = (([SKProduct]) -> Void)
typealias PurchaseCompletionHandler = ((SKPaymentTransaction?) -> Void)

class Store: NSObject, ObservableObject {

@Published var allFullVersion = [FullVersion]()

private let allProductsIdentifiers = Set ([
"ClemPapplis.OrientationEPS.versionFull"
])
private var completedPurchases = [String]() {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            for index in self.allFullVersion.indices {
                if self.completedPurchases.contains(self.allFullVersion[index].id){
                    print("completedPurchases")
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "Premium")
                }
                self.allFullVersion[index].isLocked =
                    !self.completedPurchases.contains(self.allFullVersion[index].id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use sandbox testers.
If I buy item, no problem, datas are print in console.

Did I forget something ?

Comment: Create a separate case for purchase restoration in the switch clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a few years since I used StoreKit, but I remember having an issue with restore purchases also (and yes, @ElTomato is correct, use a separate case - I'm surprised your code actually builds). I found that the following worked:

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                delegate.purchaseComplete()
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            default:
                break
            }}}
}
func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    for _ in queue.transactions {
        alreadyPurchased = true
        delegate.purchasesRestored()
    }
    showAlert("Purchases have been restored.")
}
```

Don't worry about `showAlert`, that's just an extension I have for `UIViewController`. But what I'm not seeing in your code is `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue:)`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial i think you did not select the select the none in here

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eaBL.png)

to restore in your simulator you should select none when you select none it tries to connect apple developers in app purchase configuration. give it a try and let me know.